# Angular TSLint - Cannot find builder "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, tslint

When I try to run command `ng lint --fix` cli throws this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find builder "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint".
See "C:\Users\MOE89A~1.ZAR\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Ijc3an\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

My lint confing in `angular.json`:

```
"lint": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
  "options": {
    "tsConfig": [
      "projects/wepod-app/tsconfig.app.json",
      "projects/wepod-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "projects/wepod-app/e2e/tsconfig.json"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
},
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "wepod-clients",
  "version": "3.2.3",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node patch.js && ng serve",
    "build": "node patch.js && node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run wepod-app:app-shell:production && ng run wepod-app:auth-standalone:production",
    "server": "npm run build && http-server -p 9090 -c-1 dist",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "node patch.js && ngcc",
    "postbuild": "node post-build.js",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "build-latest": "git pull origin production && npm run build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/video.js": "^7.3.27",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "bowser": "^2.11.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "compare-version": "^0.1.2",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "d3": "^6.5.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.10",
    "lottie-web": "^5.7.13",
    "lzutf8": "^0.6.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-gallery": "^5.1.1",
    "ng2-jalali-date-picker": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.5.2",
    "ngx-doughnut-chart": "0.0.4",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.2",
    "ngx-lottie": "^7.0.4",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.10.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.1.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "podchat-browser": "^10.14.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "video.js": "^7.15.4",
    "videojs-record": "^4.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.0.0",
    "@egjs/hammerjs": "^2.0.17",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.36",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "git-tag-version": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.2",
    "http-server": "^14.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.7",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.4.4",
    "zip-dir": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From v13 angular doesn't use `tslint` anymore due to [deprecation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint).

Run `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics` to add `eslint` to your application.

It will use [tslint-to-eslint-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-to-eslint-config) to migrate you to `eslint` automatically.

It will generate a `.eslintrc.json` file and migrate `tslint.json` to it.

Nothing else is needed to be done.

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics` it will do the rest automatically.

Comment: Thank you. This was suggested by the cli, but I wasn't sure if this is the correct way to do when working with ```tslint```.

Comment: Well it did not work in my case. It says "Packages installed successful", but theres no migrated .eslintrc.json, and runing ng lint still gives the same error message. I can also see that the lint config in  angular.json is still refering tslint.

Comment: What is your angular version? @PeterStjernholmMeldgaard

Comment: Looks like you now have to run `npx tslint-to-eslint-config` to get `.eslintrc.json` converted

Answer (score 17):

@MahdiJoon is a great answer! I think that it will work for most projects.

I'm adding this answer for developers who have already deleted `tslint` manually, like I did.

If you did that, like me, then:

1. `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics` to install `eslint`
2. `ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint <project-name>` to migrate `tslint.json` config to `.eslintrc.json`
3. (optional) run the previous command for any other project (e.g. `e2e`)

Comment: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'lint')

Comment: are you on angular@13? This answer has more than a year, it may need some adjustments to work with the current toolkit

Comment: yes. Angular 15. Totally up to you man, if you want to update the answer

Comment: Hi @AqeelAshiq, unfortunately I'm not working on Angular right now, if you want, send an edit request, I'll add your version to the answer