# lint config got deleted from angular.json file after angular13 upgrade

Tags: angular, lint

Have upgraded my angular version from 12 to 13, after upgrade lint configuration got removed from my angular.json file.

```
"lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
```

The above section  got removed after upgrade. But when i looked into Angular13 upgrade major changes there is no any specific information on this? So its expected for Angular13 upgrade? Please share your ideas.

Comment: Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/a/70142541